# Q: Google Calendar API, Foreground color

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am currently working with the google calendar API and and have ran into an issue.

I can't seem to update (or patch) a calendarList's foreground color.

Even when working directly with their API at:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/patch

With both queries, I have colorRgbFormat set to true, and these are the only values I provide.

This input works fine:

```
{
  "backgroundColor": "#ac725e"
}
```

Where this input:

```
{
  "backgroundColor": "#ac725e",
  "foregroundColor": "#c1c1c1"
}
```

Gives me the following error:

```
400 bad request:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid foreground color."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid foreground color."
 }
}
```

Any ideas?
I have tried using similar color format that is needed for ColorId, AKA "1", but that also gives me a bad request error.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing trial and error, I found out that the **foregroundColor** is limited only to black(**#000000**) and white (**#FFFFFF**).

**Example:**

[image]

[image]

### Reference:

- [CalendarList](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList)

Comment: Good day Nikko J.
Thanks for the feedback.
Wasn't aware that it was limited to colors. I tested it out, I also received the success 200 status.
Input example:
{
  "foregroundColor": "#000000",
  "backgroundColor": "#c1c1c1"
}
But the results in the updated CalendarList I receive back is:
{"colorId": "14",
 "backgroundColor": "#9fe1e7",
 "foregroundColor": "#000000",
}

So even with the 200 status, it doesn't seem like it is updating.

Comment: @Otomys - You have to enable colorRgbFormat. See Reference: [CalendarList](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList#resource)

Comment: Ahh crap, yeah forgot about that flag when I tested it. It is working now, thanks!
Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer, but did mark it as the correct answer.